# nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping, associative-table

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) I'm trying to create Many-to-Many Relationship Using a Composite Key
Eventually I get [the following error](https://pastebin.com/GGGtRvjt)

The composite key itself have the following structure:

```java
@Embeddable
@Data
public class MovieRatingsKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "movieid")
    private Movies movieid;

    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Usrs userid;
}
```

Class Movies:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Movies {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer movieid;

    /*not related to the question*/

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ratings> rates = new HashSet<>();
}
```

User:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Usrs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ratings> rates = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Associative table:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Ratings {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MovieRatingsKey id;
    
    /*not related to the question*/

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("movieid")
    @JoinColumn(name = "movieid")
    Movies movie;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userid")
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    Usrs user;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Usrs` you have used `userid` in `mappedBy` is should be `user` as shown below.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Usrs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ratings> rates = new HashSet<>();
}
```